# Split a pandas dataframe into two dataframes efficiently based on some condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So, I want to split a given dataframe into two dataframes based on an if condition for a particular column.
I am currently achieving this by iterating over the whole dataframe two times. Please suggest some ways to improve this.

```
 player   score
 dan       10
 dmitri    45
 darren    15
 xae12     40
```

Like in the above dataframe, I want to split the df into two such that one df contains rows with the players scoring less than 15 and the other df contains the remaining rows. I want to this with one iteration only. (Also, if the answer can be generic for n dfs, it will help me a lot) 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IICU

Use boolean select

```
m=df.score>15

Lessthan15=df[~m]
Morethan15=df[m]
```

Morethan15

[image]

LessThan15

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer...this works perfectly..but just wanted to ask how is this working behind the curtain...like is it checking true or false for each row two times ?

Comment: A boolean index is used to select the data. That is, true or false.A case in point, df.score>15 will yield either True or False if called or printed, That is, it can be accessed as a bolean index. We can also mask to the dataframe. That is what I do when I call df[m]. ~ is used to reverse the index values. boolean index can also be used to call a column value for instance df.loc[m,'score']

Comment: That explains a lot...thanks !!
Just had a query...in this case, are we checking each row for true or false twice ?

Answer (score 6):

There are two possible ways to select dataframe as per your requirement. I am doing time analysis in the same query, so that we can get the idea which one is faster.

1) **Using two times df**

```
%%time

dataframe1  = dataframe[dataframe['score']>15]
dataframe2  = dataframe[dataframe['score']<=15]
```

the output is coming in `Wall time: 4.06 ms`

2) **Using boolean and tilde concept:**

```
%%time

a = dataframe.score>15

dataframe1 = dataframe[a]
dataframe2 = dataframe[~a]
```

This query is giving output in `Wall time: 0.02 ms`

Clearly the second method is much faster.

Comment: woahh...that is a huge difference even for such a small df...thanks for the answer...
Also, can u help me in understanding like are we looping over the df twice in boolean method as well (to check for true value) ?

Comment: @Marshall You can accept the answer if you think it is solved. That's how this community works. It will helpful for future visitors too.

Comment: @Anshul Vyas is using others answers and combining them. Marshall we cant tell you who to mark right but uuummm...

Comment: Actually...that is correct..my bad!! I'm pretty new to the platform.

Comment: @wwnde I am sorry, If I hurt sentiments of the experts here, Many a time I was also asked to accept the answer in the comments from the senior community members.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df_less_than_15 = df[df['score'] < 15]
df_more_than_15 = df[df['score'] >= 15]
```

you can use the same thing for every given data frame.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply....but this is looping over the df two times..I intend to do it over a single iteration.